# Load XML and get tag. Change from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xml, tags

I have a server-side script but now I want it run on client-side, so I want to convert from php to javascript. I am really not good at js so, please help.

Php code here:

```
    function getAlexaRank($theUrl)
    {
        $alexa_url = "http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=" . $theUrl;
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->load($alexa_url);

        $popularities = $doc->getElementsByTagName("POPULARITY");
        foreach($popularities as $popularity)
        {
            return $popularity->getAttribute('TEXT');
        }
        return "-1";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following link to acheive it using js

http://www.hiteshagrawal.com/javascript/javascript-parsing-xml-in-javascript